# Labeling a game board

Tags: python

I am not really sure how to label the rows and columns in the table. If I want both the rows and columns to be labeled numerically, do I create a separate function or do I just add it to this existing code? Thank you for your help!

```
class GameLogic:
    def __init__(self, row, column):
        self._self = self
        self._column = column
        self._row = row
    def create_board(self):
        self._board = []
        for row in range(1,self._row+1):
            row = ''
            for col in range(1,self._column+1):
                if self._board == ' ':
                    row = ' '
                else:
                    row =  '. '
                print(row, end = '')
            print()
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "labeled"?

Comment: You have omitted a lot of details. Do you want the Y axis labelled on the left edge or right edge? From top to bottom or bottom to top? Starting at 0 or 1? Will the label ever be more than one digit? And likewise with the X axis.

Comment: Strictly speaking you should have a GameModel (which keeps the board contents but not the labels) and a GameView (which draws the board and labels to screen). Less strictly, you can do whatever works and makes you happy ;-)

Comment: I would like to label the rows and columns starting from 1, beginning at the top left corner.